# How Do I Send An Message To A Running Yarn Application?

Tags: rest, hadoop-yarn

I want to have my application already started on my YARN cluster and allow the users to send additional commands. I am still in the design phase, but I'm confused on the best way about going about this. Is this possible? Could the user send some sort of REST command to the Application Master or Resource Manager that could then be passed to the running YARN Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you're willing to build a custom AM and write your own REST API but writing a custom AM is not trivial.  As for the RM, you can kill your application or move to another queue via REST API calls but not much else.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html